# How to use str_word-count() with utf-8 so that it prints special characters

Tags: php, special-characters

I have this piece of code (running on Php 7) which will print out the frequency of words. The function works, however, special characters are not printed, probably because of `str_word_count()`.

```
// Random words
$freqData = array();
$keywords = "Başka, Başka, küskün küskün otomobil kaçtı buraya küskün otomobil neden kaçtı
          kaçtı buraya, oraya KISMEN @here #there J.J.Johanson hep.
          Danny:Where is mom? I don't know! Café est weiß for 2 €uros.
          My 2nd nickname is mike18.";

// Set letter count to exclude words like 'and'/'or', etc.
$letterCount = 5;

// Get individual words and build a frequency table
foreach (str_word_count($keywords, 1) as $word) {
    // If the word has more than x letters
    if (mb_strlen($word, 'UTF-8') >= $letterCount) {
        // For each word found in the frequency table, increment its value by one
        array_key_exists($word, $freqData) ? $freqData[$word]++ : $freqData[$word] = 0;
    }
}
echo $freqData;
```

I have `<meta charset="UTF-8">` in the `<head>` section.
How can I solve this?

Comment: How do you "*print*" the special characters? Do you mean, that they are not counted for the `$letterCount` comparison, or do you litterally print them on screen and they are not shown? If it is the latter, please provide the code you use to *print* them.

Comment: Using echo - I updated the code.

Comment: I ended up adding a charlist of letters like this: `foreach (str_word_count($keywords, 1, 'şçøæåé1233456789') as $word) {}`